# Shading issues showing in rendered Cycles viewport but not in solid viewport

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, shaders, geometry

For some reason when I render the object in viewport 3D Render I see these lines that look like weird shading or geometry. But I have fixed this in the Solid Viewport where they don't show up. Also I noticed I only have this problem in Cycles if I turn the Engine to Eevee it looks normal. How do I solve this? [image][image]

Comment: Can you post your wireframe?

Comment: https://ibb.co/zG1snnf
https://ibb.co/0Xjd4Jk
https://ibb.co/r4V1Lh9
https://ibb.co/xHdMs1Z
https://ibb.co/9p4Trn2

Comment: I uploaded the images here both in wireframe and with normals. The normals seems ok and I already used autosmooth and shade smooth on the object, but I tried reapplying it again to see if there was any change but nothing happend. I also tried flipping the normals but that just made it worse. The strange thing is also if I render the object in Evee it looks all perfectly smooth but when I change it to Cycles it becomes deformed like this in the viewport.

Comment: hello, could you please share the object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/2c732370d43a4870890836ba8c752050

Comment: Please add the wireframe images to the question body by editing it so people can see it and help.
Is the whole object one single mesh? By looking at the wireframes you linked it looks like the ofending face might be an n-gon in the shape of an upside-down L. Try connecting the 'loose' corner in the extruded part to the  vertex of the main cylinder. Unless they are separate parts, of course.

Comment: If you could upload the blend file I will take a look

Comment: I uploaded the file here https://easyupload.io/7y4nnc and the screen shots of the wire frame are posted in the 5 links I posted above.

Comment: Fixed the Issue through this post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237527/shading-issue-with-object

Answer (score 0):

It could be any number of things, if you post the wireframe, or the area in edit mode that could help narrow it down! :)

Some stuff to try, though:

- Merge vertices by distance to get rid of any doubled up geometry.
- Turn on Auto Smooth in the Object Data Properties>Normals area and mess with the Angle until it looks good and see if that helps. Probably not but sometimes auto smoothing can force things to work when they otherwise wouldn't.
- Re-apply Shade Smooth - Seems simple but sometimes after changes, particularly when sculpting, but sometimes in other areas as well, the shading smooth needs to be reapplied to take effect on the altered area.
- Check your normals. [image] In edit mode, use the overlay drop down as pictured and near the bottom tick the Face Orientation option and see if the problem area has any RED. If it does it means the face is not oriented correctly and needs to be flipped. Select it or the entire mesh while still in edit mode and hit Shift+N to flip normals.
- Fix geo. This sounds obvious but these problems usually don't show up if the geometry is solid. Make sure there's no edges split, no loose vertices, non-manifold geometry etc.
- Try adding the Weld modifier to the mesh or applying modifiers if you have any attached to the mesh in question, sometimes they can cause issues that may show up until they are applied.

Comment: Fixed the issue through this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237527/shading-issue-with-object