# Shading issue with object

Tags: modeling, rendering, shaders, lighting, geometry

I have created an object, when I render it in EEVEE the shading looks decent but when I render it in Cycles it seems to have clear lines where the shading falls.

I tried a shade transfer from another object, but that didn't work, I tried to add subdivision which messed up the mesh, and adding loopcuts didn't really seem to do the trick too.

Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

I uploaded the file here in case if anyone wants to have a better look at it. https://easyupload.io/49yd8k

Comment: It looks like normals trouble, but why it’s happening for cycles and not EEVEE I have no idea. Are some of the normals inverted? Do you need to merge duplicate verses? Do you have odd n-gon shapes / does triangulating the mash make a huge difference?

Comment: It is an artifact of your first Bevel modifier, on the panel on the main cylinder; but I don't know the fix.

Comment: I don't think it's an artifact because then it would show up in the face orientation don't you think? I also checked the normals and that seemed in order. It could be the geometry which need to be of a rounded shape for that position. But I have no Idea how to do that. Because if I add loopcuts the shape will still have sharp edges and I can't really use a latice or deform it will affect the whole object instead of that face or edge only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's the *Terminator Effect*, Blender struggles to create soft shadows with the current lights (you have areas that project parallel rays and a point light that has a very low *Radius* value), you need to increase the size of a light, like the *Radius* of the light called *Light*, or select your object and in the *Object panel > Shading*, increase the *Shadow Terminator Offset*.

Here I've just increased the *Radius* of *Light*:

[image]